# Running multiple threads at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading

So my goal is to have the `do_something()` function kickoff its own thread so that `do_something()` can run in parallel instead of having to wait for the previous one to finish. The problem is that it seems like it is not multithreading (meaning one thread finishes before the other one starts).

```
for i in range(len(array_of_letters)):

    if i == "a":
        t = threading.Thread(target=do_something())

        print "new thread started : %s"%(str(threading.current_thread().ident))     
        t.start()
```

I also have a `current_thread().ident` inside of the `do_something()` function but it seems like the identity of the thread that is started is the same as the main thread that the python script is running from.  I think my approach is incorrect.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre is correct, I believe, about the immediate problem. Even with that fixed, you should be aware that in Python threads don't really run at the same time because for the most part the Python interpreter can't really interpret two or more different threads of execution simultaneously (and has something called the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) to prevent it. Instead, what happens is it runs one thread until it blocks waiting for a shared resource, does I/O, or calls `sleep()`, and only then does it switches to running another one (if any) which is waiting for its turn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common and easy to fall for mistake.

`target=do_something()` just executes your function at once in the main thread and passes `None` (the returning value of your function I suppose) as `target` function to the thread, which does not trigger any visible error; but does nothing either.

you have to pass the actual function not the result:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=do_something)
```

will work better

Comment: Yes one of the evil token pairs `()` and `[]` stroke again - nice explanation IMO.